# how to change pyarrow table column precision for multi level index/column DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I have a pyarrow.Table that's created from a pandasDataFrame

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1.0, 2.0],  "col2": [2.3, 2.4]})
    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a',100),('b',200)], names=('name', 'number'))
    df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a',100),('b',200)], names=('name', 'number'))

    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
```

The original df has thousands of columns and rows, and the values are all `float64`, and therefore become `double` when I convert to pyarrow Table

How can I change them all to `float32`?

I tried the following:

```
    schema = pa.schema([pa.field("('a',100)", pa.float32()),pa.field("('b',200)", pa.float32()),])
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema=schema)
```

but that complains about the schema and the dataframe not matching: `KeyError: "name '('a',100)' present in the specified schema is not found in the columns or index"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the table to the types you need

```
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
table = table.cast(pa.schema([("('a', '100')", pa.float32()), 
                              ("('b', '200')", pa.float32()), 
                              ("name", pa.string()), 
                              ("number", pa.string())]))
```

I doubt you will find a way to provide a working schema to `Table.from_pandas` when using a Pandas multikey index. The name of the column in that case is a `tuple` (`('a', 100)`) but for Arrow `schema` column names can only be strings. So you will never be able to create a schema that points to the same column names that the dataframe has.

That's why casting afterward works, because *after* you made an Arrow table (and thus all column names became strings) you can finally provide the string equal to the column name to the cast function.

Answer (score 1):

First convert the data frame to a table and then change the schema so that every float64 is turned to float32:

```
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
schema = pa.schema(
    [
        pa.field(f.name, pa.float32() if f.type == pa.float64() else f.type) 
        for f in table.schema
    ]
)

table.cast(schema)
```

Comment: Thank you. this is extremely helpful! I came across another trouble with multi level index/columns though, and just updated my question a bit. Can you help take another look? Thank you so much!

Comment: Your editted question is very different from the original, next time please ask another question.